# Finding citations

Tags: united-states, legal-research, legal-citation

I’ve occasionally asked questions ([example](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/92547/equal-protection-discrimination-and-real-estate)) that could be easily answered by Shepard’s Citations—if I still had access.  **How should I search for citations of a statute or case without paying Lexis or traveling to some place that has the print edition?**

I can search the [Cornell LII](https://www.law.cornell.edu) for a particular citation, but if it has spaces, I get all the hits for any part.  But when I tried to get "exact phrase" by quoting *311 U.S. 32*, there were zero results, which I know is not correct.

Comment: Related: [FAQ Online Legal References](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/261/35069)

Comment: Those are great for looking up a case or statute.  Not so useful for finding a case that CITES a particular statute or other case.

Answer (score 2):

> How should I search for citations of a statute or case without paying
> Lexis or traveling to some place that has the print edition?

There are no good free sources for this at this time for U.S. law. Essentially, this service is what legal publishers are now all relying upon to make money.